# Some apps do not start or print any message/error

Tags: google-chrome, gnome-shell

Today I booted my laptop (Ubuntu 20.04) up just to realize that some apps do not start/open.
The affected apps are:

- Google Chrome
- GitKraken
- Slack
- Drawio

but there might be others. Even if I try to start them using the terminal nothing is printed (no error or message). Even if I try to just print the help message (google-chrome --help), nothing happens.

In the system monitor GUI (or "ps aux" in the terminal) I can see that the processes are running.

What I have tried so far:

- Disable all gnome extensions
- Reboot
- Reinstall both apps (latest versions)
- Downgrade google-chrome to version 81
- Remove `~/.config/google-chrome` folder
- Try without any external monitor

I do not think there is something wrong with the app themselves because the problem is identical for both of them.

Some additional info:

`Linux zion 5.4.0-40-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 23 00:01:04 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

```
ii  google-chrome-stable                                        83.0.4103.116-1                       amd64        The web browser from Google
ii  gitkraken                                                   7.0.1                                 amd64        Unleash your repo
ii  slack-desktop                                               4.7.0                                 amd64        Slack Desktop
ii  draw.io                                                     13.0.1-294                                  amd64
```

**EDIT1**: all above apps works fine on KDE so I think it is a Gnome Shell problem. Time to say goodbye to Gnome and switch to KDE ...

**EDIT2**: I tried again today (after 3 weeks) and the problem is still the same, despite a newer version of chrome (84.0.4147.89).

Comment: All the apps you listed are based on Chromium/Electron, so I think there's a connection there. Also does `google-chrome --help` work on KDE but not on GNOME? That's strange...

Comment: In KDE everything works ... by the way Chromium itself works both in Gnome and KDE.

Comment: I have same problem with slack after 4.7.0 upgrade today. I'm seeing segfault on syslog

Comment: I installed slack via apt instead of snapd and problem solved.

Comment: I had installed slack via apt ...

Comment: Having exact same issue with Slack installed from (damn) snap store, updated to version 4.7.0 today.
Snapd seems to be broken all around. 
Chromium works for me (!Google Chrome), but it installs it via snapd no matter what you do on apt (for this reason, Linux Mint got rid of snapd in latest LTS release based on Ubuntu 20.04).

So this segfault tells us nothing, no CoreDump, nothing.

`ryzen kernel: ThreadPoolForeg[11037]: segfault at 34d0 ip 00000000000034d0 sp 00007fd365edfde8 error 14`

Comment: But this shows clear reference to Chrome threads (slack internals)
`ryzen kernel: traps: Chrome_IOThread[10948] trap int3 ip:55cac9b8c1c4 sp:7fcb439077e0 error:0 in slack[55cac7700000+5caf000]`